# Is it mandatory to have a doGet or doPost method?

Tags: java, servlets

I have few questions.

1. Can i have a Servlet without these two methods?
2. Can i call my form directly to Service method... Like

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class FormServlet extends HttpServlet {

protected void doService (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

}
```

Comment: Why would you want a servlet that cannot be used by anyone? They only way clients can contact a servlet is either through GET, POST, PUT, or DELETE. Imho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will note that the `service()` method originates from the `javax.servlet.GenericServlet` and not `javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet`.

If you want to do something with a servlet which doesn't involve the **http protocol**, I would say go ahead.

In the Head First Servlets and JSP they explain this in detail. 99% You will make use of the `HttpServlet`.

By extending `GenericServlet`, the servlet would run regardless of the content submitted. As long as the URL is fired the `service()` method will execute.

Answer (score 4):

1. Yes, you can have a servlet without either of these methods (they have no implementation). Still having a HttpServlet without having doGet/doPost seems a bit pointless, since servlet can only communicate with the a limited number of request methods such as `GET`, `POST`, `DELETE`, `PUT` (for more see [specification section 5.1.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html) ).
2. HttpServlet don't have `doService` methods. If you meant  `void service()` then I advise you not to mess with it unless you really know what you're doing. 
   If all you need is to use `doService` call it from `doGet`, `doPost` (as someone already suggested).

Ok, examples:

```
public class DoesNothingServlet extends HttpServlet {} //does what the name implies

public class FormServlet extends HttpServlet { //what you want to do

  protected doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws   ServletException, IOException {
        doService(request,response)
  }

  protected void doService (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws   ServletException, IOException {
        //Do something
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not mandatory. Since `HttpServlet` is an abstract class, there are abstract implementations of all `doXXX` methods, and you don't have to implement them if you don't want to.

Answer (score 1):

Read http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html

> Provides an abstract class to be subclassed to create an HTTP servlet suitable for a Web site. A subclass of HttpServlet must override at least one method, usually one of these:
>
> - doGet, if the servlet supports HTTP GET requests
> - doPost, for HTTP POST requests
> - doPut, for HTTP PUT requests
> - doDelete, for HTTP DELETE requests
> - init and destroy, to manage resources that are held for the life of the servlet
> - getServletInfo, which the servlet uses to provide information about itself

From your doGet and doPost methods, you can call your doService(..,..) method if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding, if I got you correct, is you want your HTTP GET, POST, (PUT, DELETE) to call your `doService` method. If that's the case, you can do this.

```
protected doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws   ServletException, IOException {
        doService(request,response)
  }

protected doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws   ServletException, IOException {
        doService(request,response)
  }
```

If you extends `HttpServlet` you don't have to override `doGet` and `doPost` as it's already implemented by `HttpServlet`. Servlet request get handled by the `service()` method which then (based on the HTTP request method) calls its relevant `doXXX` method.

I wouldn't mess with the `service()` method though, unless you know what you're doing.